# The way to export data of CTF format from "Experiments" in Tracecompass?

Tags: lttng, eclipse-tracecompass

I'm using TraceCompass to see the Lttng log.
Sometimes I import Kernel and Userspace traces at the same time and integrate them into "Experiments" to be able to see it in one profile.

Does anyone know how to exports this integrated kernel and userspace traces into one CTF-formated log, not separated each other?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trace compass attributes a trace type to a trace. Merging two traces would results in one trace with two types. This doesn't work under the current architecture. A trace cannot be a kernel and userspace trace at once.

An alternative I would recommend is to [export](https://rtist.hcldoc.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.tracecompass.doc.user%2Fdoc%2FTrace-Compass-Main-Features.html) an experiment and then import the trace package. It does not merge the files, but gives you a handy zip file with all the traces as well as the indexes/state systems.